# SharePoint 2016 Error: Cannot edit any Page Layouts and create any new SP pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sharepoint-addin, page-layout

I have SharePoint 2016 error with edit any details page take any Page Layout and create new any SP pages also. And I checked the log and I got this error message

Can you help ?

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.ContentTypeIdFieldType.GetFieldValue(String value) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValueFromSafeArrayObject(Object obj, SPField fld) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Item(Guid fieldId) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_AssociatedContentTypeId() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_AssociatedContentType() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_UIDisplayName() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayoutComparerByUIDisplayName.Compare(PageLayout x, PageLayout y) 
at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.DepthLimitedQuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer, Int32 depthLimit) 
at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
```

Comment: can you run PSconfig if finished successfully?

Comment: Yes I tried the PSconfig and it's successfully. But the error still exist

Comment: have you tried create new site collection and edit the page here if the problem is global or only on one site?

Comment: I think the problem in the site. So I will create new site collection and if the problem still exist I will get back to you .

Comment: if its only on the site, try to reactivate Publishing features with PowerShell and -force parameter

Comment: I tried to create new site collection and once I make deploy a solution the error still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue does not exist on other site collections, then check your custom page layouts, try to remove custom page layouts, and test again

Comment: I tried to create new site collection and once deploy a solution the error still exist. So I will try to remove all custom page layouts and try again ..

Comment: Yes you are right man, I checked all custom page layouts and I found the problem and resolved that...  thanks man :)